# If $f \in C^1$ and limit of derivative exists, does the limit of $f$ exist?

Tags: analysis, limits

Suppose $f$ is a function on $(0,1)$ contained in class $C^1$.

If

$$\lim_{x\to 1^-} f '(x) \text{ exists, then }\lim_{x\to 1^-} f(x)\text{ exists?}$$

Probably it is true but how can I prove it?

Comment: Either you meant $\;\lim_{x\to 1^-}f(x)\;$ right after "then", or else you simply meant $\;f(1)\;$ , without the limit.

Comment: Oh sorry. I omitted lim x-> 1- . @Timbuc

Comment: you *also* wrote $\;f(1)\;$ and **not** $\;f(x)\;$ . If it is as you say you must also change this.

Comment: Ignore the answer I just deleted if you can see it. The question isn't displaying correctly for me so I answered the wrong question.

Comment: What does the fact that f is in C1 tell you?

Answer (score 2):

Assume $\lim_{x\to1-} f'(x)=\alpha\in{\mathbb R}$. Given an $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that $$|f'(x)|\leq 1+|\alpha|\qquad(1-\delta < x<1)\ .$$ Put $$\delta':=\min\left\{\delta,{\epsilon\over 1+|\alpha|}\right\}>0\ .$$
When $x$, $y\in\ ]1-\delta',1[\ $, by the MVT there is a $\tau$ between $x$ and $y$ such that
$$|f(x)-f(y)|=f'(\tau)|x-y|\leq\bigl(1+|\alpha|\bigr){\epsilon\over 1+|\alpha|}\leq\epsilon\ .$$
This says that $x\mapsto f(x)$ satisfies the Cauchy condition when $x\to1-$. Therefore the $\lim_{x\to1-}f(x)$ exists.

Answer (score 1):

Since g'(x) is continuous , we can define a function h such that

h is a function on $\;[1/2 , 1]\;$  where h(t) = $ \int_{1/2}^t{g'(x)dx} $ - $g(1/2)$

Since $\;lim_{x\to1^-} g'(x)\;$ exists, (0,1) can extend to (0,1] where it is domain of $g'(x)$

And extended function g' is bounded on [1/2 , 1] impies that it can integral 1/2 to 1.

Hence function h is well-defined

Note that f(x) = h(x) where x is in [1/2 , 1) and lim h(x) x -> 1^- exists.

Therefore lim f(x) x -> 1^- also exists

Is it right?

Comment: It is correct if you take $h(x) = g(1/2) + \int_{1/2}^x g'(t)dt$ (check the sign).

Comment: haha;;; I always mistake something. Thank you

Comment: But, again, this is true only if the limit of $f'$ exists and it is finite.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\lim_{x\to 1^-} f'(x)$ exists the function $f'$ is bounded on the interval $\left(\frac{1}{2} ,1\right)$ and hence the function $f$ is uniformly continuous on the interval $\left(\frac{1}{2} ,1\right)$, so therefore the limit $\lim_{x\to 1^-} f(x)$ exists.

Comment: You mean f ' is uniformly continuous ?

Comment: No, $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have two different limits:
$$
f(x_k) \to \ell_1, \qquad f(x_j) = \ell_2
$$
with $x_k\to 1^-$ and $x_j\to 1^-$. Then for $k$ and $j$ sufficiently large you are able to find points $x_k$ and $x_j$ where the incremental ratio
$$
  \frac{f(x_k) - f(x_j)}{x_k-x_j}
$$
either goes to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$. In the interval $[x_k,x_j]$ there is a point where the derivative is equal to the incremental ratio, so also the derivative has subsequences going to $+\infty$ and to $-\infty$.

Comment: How about $lim_{x\to1^-}f(x)$ is infinite ?

Comment: It is possible that the limit of $f$ is infinite and the limit of $f'$ exists. Take $f(x) =  1/(1-x)$.

Comment: limit of f′ does not exist

Comment: $\lim_{x\to 1^-} f'(x) = \lim_{x\to 1^-} \frac{1}{(1-x)^2} = +\infty$, it exists even if it is not finite.

Answer (score 0):

Your conjecture is true. You can prove it as follows. Put $$M_1 := \left|\lim_{x\rightarrow 1^-} f'(x)\right|.$$

Then there is an $n_1 \in \mathbb N$ such that $$\left|f'(x)\right| \leq 2M_1 \quad for \quad x \in [1-1/n_1,1).$$ This follows from continuity of $f'$ and existence of $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1^-} f'(x)$. Consider the sequence $$y_k := 1 - 1/k\quad for \quad k \in \{n_1, n_1 + 1, \ldots \}.$$ Just for convenience, we start the indexing at $n_1$ instead of at $1$. With that, we define the sequence $$z_k := f(y_k) - f(1/2) = \int_{1/2}^{y_k} f'(t)dt\quad for \quad k \in \{n_1, n_1 + 1, \ldots \}.$$ Here, the choice of $1/2$ is completely arbitrary. Now, for integers $p,q$ with $p,q \geq n_1$, we have $$\left|z_p - z_q\right| = \left|\int_{y_p}^{y_q} f'(t)dt \right| \leq \left|1/p - 1/q\right| 2M_1.$$ Here, the r.h.s. tends to $0$ as $p,q \rightarrow \infty$. This implies that the sequence $z_k$ is Cauchy and has a limit $$z := lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} z_k.$$

Now, pick an $\epsilon > 0$ and find an $n_2 \geq n_1$ such that $1/{n_2} < \epsilon$ and $|z_{n_2} - z| < \epsilon$. Please convince yourself that such an $n_2$ indeed exists. Then, for $x \in (y_{n_2},1)$ we find $$\left|f(x) - f(1/2) - z_{n_2} \right| = \left| \int_{1/2}^x f'(t)dt - z_{n_2}\right| = \left|\int_{y_{n_2}}^xf'(t)dt\right| \leq \left(x-y_{n_2}\right)2M_1 \leq (1-y_{n_2})2M_1= (1/n_2)2M_1 < \epsilon 2M_1.$$ This in turn gives us
$$\left|f(x) - f(1/2) - z \right| \leq \left|f(x) - f(1/2) - z_{n_2} \right| + \left| z_{n_2} - z \right| \leq \epsilon 2M_1 + \epsilon$$
for $x \in (y_{n_2},1)$. Since $\epsilon > 0$ was arbitrary, we have shown that
$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 1^-}\left(f(x) - f(1/2)\right) = z.$$

Of course, this is equivalent to the existence of $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1^-} f(x)$